# Force SHA when user changes LDAP password using passwd

Tags: centos, ssh, ldap, pam

I'm trying to setup PAM/LDAP so that when a logged in SSH user changes their password using `passwd`, it encrypts the password with `SHA1` before updating the LDAP entry. I have this

```
# /etc/ldap.conf
...
rootbinddn cn=Manager,dc=ourdomain,dc=com
rootpw secret
pam_crypt local
```

When a user changes their password using `passwd`, in LDAP, the entry looks something like this

```
{crypt}41H84HEld3
```

So it's coming over as `crypt`. I'm not sure how to force it to be `SHA / SHA1`. I tried adding

```
pam_password sha
```

to `/etc/ldap.conf` but then the password just comes over and is stored in LDAP as clear text.

Answer (score 3):

From this [source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-upgrading-password-hashing/), in RHEL|CentOS 5:

> #### Display Current Hashing Algorithm
>
> Type the following command:
>       # authconfig --test | grep hashing
>
> #### Sample outputs:

```
    password hashing algorithm is md5
```

> #### Configure Linux Server To Use The SHA-512
>
> To configure the Linux system to use the SHA-512 algorithm, enter:
>           # authconfig --passalgo=sha512 --update
>
> *Note: users need to change their passwords in order to generate hashes using SHA-512. You can force users to change their password on next login:*

```
    # chage -d 0 userName
```

I have not tried it (only have CentOS 4 handy), but hope it helps.